# Position of first ocurrence in every row according to condition

Tags: r

I have the following table, with ordered variables:

```
table <- data.frame(Ident = c("Id_01", "Id_02", "Id_03", "Id_04", "Id_05", "Id_06"), 
                    X01 = c(NA, 18, 0, 14, 0, NA), 
                    X02 = c(0, 16, 0, 17, 0, 53), 
                    X03 = c(NA, 15, 20, 30, 0, 72), 
                    X04 = c(0, 17, 0, 19, 0, NA), 
                    X05 = c(NA, 29, 21, 23, 0, 73), 
                    X06 = c(0, 36, 22, 19, 0, 55))

Ident   X01 X02 X03 X04 X05 X06
Id_01   NA  0   NA  0   NA  0
Id_02   18  16  15  17  29  36
Id_03   0   0   20  0   21  22
Id_04   14  17  30  19  23  19
Id_05   0   0   0   0   0   0
Id_06   NA  53  72  NA  73  55
```

I would like to find, for each Ident, when the first occurence appear according to an specific condition. For example, two *consecutive* numbers > 0:

> For Id_01: never occurs (NA?)
>
> For Id_02: 1st position (X01)
>
> For Id_03: 5th position (X05)
>
> For Id_04: 1st position (X01)
>
> For Id_05: never occurs (NA?)
>
> For Id_06: 2nd position (X02)

I'm trying to find the position number OR the variable name of that position.

---

EDIT:
I'm looking to add a second condition to the `apply` solution posted below, so the conditions needs to be:

1. 1st and 2nd ocurrence (consecutive) > 0 **OR**
2. 1st and 3rd ocurrence > 0

Considering this change, the output of the evaluation for the table posted before should be:

> For Id_01: never occurs (NA?)
>
> For Id_02: 1st position (X01)
>
> For Id_03: 3rd position (X03) - *not X05*
>
> For Id_04: 1st position (X01)
>
> For Id_05: never occurs (NA?)
>
> For Id_06: 2nd position (X02)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `apply` to loop through the rows, create a logical expression that checks whether the numbers are greater than 0 or not an NA ('i1').  Then, compare the adjacent two elements by removing the first and last element  i.e.checking for two TRUE and get the index with `which`.  Use that to get the column names

```
apply(table[-1], 1, function(x) {
    i1 <- x > 0 & !is.na(x)
    names(x)[which(i1[-1] & i1[-length(i1)])[1]]})
#[1] NA    "X01" "X05" "X01" NA    "X02"
```

Comment: Took some time to get the logic for the two-in-a-row, brilliant!

Comment: @akrun I'm trying to add a second condition to the apply formula (1st and 3rd number > 0), I assume that this is done modifying the [-1] value to the which statement but it's not working: `names(x)[which(i1[-1] & i1[-length(i1)] | i1[-2] & i1[-length(i1)])[1]]})`. What I'm doing wrong? Thx

Comment: @CristianS.  May be you need `if( x[1] > 0 & x[3] > 0) i1 <- x > 0 & !is.na(x)` ?

Comment: @akrun Gives me an error, I assume that's because of defining the if statement before i1. I was thinking about adding a second condition (using | ) in the which statement at the end of the code. Finally, the point is to evaluate if the 1st and 2nd values, or the 1st and 3rd values are > 0 using the same apply.

Comment: @CristianS.  Can you please update your question or post as a new question as I am not clear about the expected output

Answer (score 1):

One way for the variable name of that position:

```
library(magrittr)
apply(!is.na(table[-1]) & table[-1] > 0, 1, 
      function(x) ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum)) %>%
  apply(2, function(x) names(table)[which(x == 2)[1]])

[1] NA    "X01" "X05" "X01" NA    "X02"
```

Or the indices:

```
apply(!is.na(table[-1]) & table[-1] > 0, 1, 
      function(x) ave(x, cumsum(x == 0), FUN = cumsum)) %>%
  apply(2, function(x) which(x == 2)[1] - 1L)

[1] NA  1  5  1 NA  2
```